# NgxsModule.forRoot([]) in child module (instead of app.module.ts)

Tags: angular, angular-module, ngxs, angular-injector

I am trying to use Ngxs only in one of my components in application.
When I import NgxsModule.forRoot([]) in my child module where I will be using it I'm getting this error and whole application is not working:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken USER_PROVIDED_NGXS_EXECUTION_STRATEGY!
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken USER_PROVIDED_NGXS_EXECUTION_STRATEGY!
```

**child-component.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
    CommonModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([ChildState],  { developmentMode: isDevMode() }),
  ]
})
export class ChildComponentModule { }
```

this solution also not working

**child-component.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
    NgxsModule.forFeature([ChildState]),

  ]
})
export class ChildComponentModule { }
```

When I import NgxsModule.forRoot([]) in app.module.ts everything is working.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChildComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]),

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**child-component.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxsModule.forFeature([ChildState]),

  ]
})
export class ChildComponentModule { }
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue and use ngxs **only** where I need it without importing it in app.module.ts
Is importing in app.module.ts obligatory?